# Table-valued-function with parameters via OPENDATASOURCE

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

Since i know that remote TVF calls are not allowed, i desperately searched for a way to do it with OPENDATASOURCE. I have something like this:

```
exec OPENDATASOURCE 
('SQLOLEDB', 
 'Server=HP10007712;initial catalog=testdb;
  User ID=admin;Password=admin;').testdb.dbo.getCdsCurve 'parm1', 'parm2'
```

which unsurprisingly yields

```
The request for procedure 'getCdsCurve' failed because 'getCdsCurve' 
is a table valued function object.
```

The question is, how can i add a SELECT to it, in order to receive the returned data?

Comment: I would use linked server instead, that will give you better access to the other server. [linked servers documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

Comment: TVFs are by design not allowed among linked servers :(